# Asp.net core file download corrupt

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've been trying to provide an epub download in various ways. All of them work when downloading on my laptop with any browser, but when downloading with the e-reader it results in either a "file is corrupt" or "content type not supported". The problem is not with the file itself: When I upload it to any other place (e.g. public file dump websites) I can download the file without any issues to my e-reader.

Here's one of the many ways I've tried:

```
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);
IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(filename);
var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
var fileType = "application/epub+zip"; //MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet
return File(readStream, fileType, Path.GetFileName(outputFilepath));
```

and on the razor page e.g.:

```
<a href="3/Epub2/test.epub">Epub2</a>
<a href="3/Epub2/test.epub" download="test.epub" type="application/epub+zip" target="_blank">Epub2</a>
```

(here the first link results in "corrupt file" and the second in "content type not supported).
On the server, the file is placed outside the website root.
What are some possible reasons that the direct download to my e-reader doesn't work with this code, yet with plain file uploads/downloads it works?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you make a binary comparison of the original file and the downloaded file? What has changed? Also, do other file types work?

Comment: Hmm the Ubuntu diff tool says they differ. The first file was created on Ubuntu, downloaded to Windows, then uploaded to that same Ubuntu server again. The other file is the first one. I hadn't mentioned this before: The server is run on Ubuntu, then I download to a "Tolino" e-reader.

Comment: Unzipped they are the same. Hmm not sure how else I should compare them...

Comment: So, I just replaced the file with one I had downloaded and then used to upload to a random file host (which then worked). I still had the same issues, which means that the problem seems to be definitely coming from the asp.net core code, it's not about the file itself.

Comment: Try a binary diff tool, e.g. [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/968863) to see what has actually changed. I wonder if there is just some additional bytes added to the beginning or end, or whether the file has major changes. The result could give a hint of what’s going on.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I made the following test: Download the ebook (from Ubuntu to Windows), upload it to a filehost, download it again, upload it to Ubuntu, make a diff. The first test resulted in identical files. The second test too.  I don't know why I said the first time that the tool says they differ, maybe it was a mistake...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the download over https to my Tolino e-reader. This specific old Tolino model has issues with downloads over https, when I switched to http I could successfully download the ebook.